# Merging collections to json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have 2 json format, namely jsonA and jsonB, in which i would like to combine into jsonC as follow.
Appreciate if someone can tell me how to do it.

jsonA

```
{
    "text1": "Hello",
    "text2": "Hi",
    "text3": "There"
}
```

jsonB

```
[
    {
        "id": "text1",
        "category": "Big"
    },
    {
        "id": "text2",
        "category": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": "text3",
        "category": "Small"
    },
]
```

Final

```
[
    {
        "id": "text1",
        "category": "Big",
        "message": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "id": "text2",
        "category": "Medium",
        "message": "Hi"
    },
    {
        "id": "text3",
        "category": "Small",
        "message": "There"
    }
]
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have there is an object and an array.

Comment: Take a stab at it, and if you run into trouble, ask a specific question about the problem you've run into.

Comment: is that `"id": "text1"` always the same?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for pointing out. I mistype it. Have updated in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for a new array.

Basically it iterates the array and build a new object for every found object. It adds a new property `message` with the wanted content form `objectA`.

```js
var objectA = { "text1": "Hello", "text2": "Hi", "text3": "There" },
    objectB = [{ "id": "text1", "category": "Big" }, { "id": "text2", "category": "Medium" }, { "id": "text3", "category": "Small" }],
    objectC = objectB.map(function (a) {
        return {
            id: a.id,
            category: a.category,
            message: objectA[a.id]
        };
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(objectC, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Soulution for a mutated array.

This solution takes the array and adds in the loop a new property with the value from `objectA`.

```js
var objectA = { "text1": "Hello", "text2": "Hi", "text3": "There" },
    objectB = [{ "id": "text1", "category": "Big" }, { "id": "text2", "category": "Medium" }, { "id": "text3", "category": "Small" }];

objectB.forEach(function (a) {
    a.message = objectA[a.id];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(objectB, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, You need to traverse 2nd json array. Than traverse 1st json and compare for indexing. If indexing matches then add new attribute to 2nd json.

Here is full example :

var jsonA = '{"text1": "Hello","text2": "Hi","text3": "There"}';

var jsonB = '[{"id": "text1","category": "Big"},{"id": "text1","category": "Medium"},{"id": "text1","category": "Small"}]';

```
jsonA = JSON.parse(jsonA);  
jsonB = JSON.parse(jsonB);  

for(var i=0;i<jsonB.length;i++){
    for(var j in jsonA){            
        if(j == ("text"+(i+1))){
            jsonB[i].message = jsonA[j];                
        }               
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonB));
```

Output : [{"id":"text1","category":"Big","message":"Hello"},{"id":"text1","category":"Medium","message":"Hi"},{"id":"text1","category":"Small","message":"There"}]